# How to properly fix dry wall tearing away

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

How can I properly fix dry wall that is tearing away from the seam, which is a window sill?

There is a point were it meets the window and window sill, and it seems to be tearing away. I have added a picture below. What would cause drywall to do this?

[image: picture of drywall damage]

Answer (score 10):

Fix the leak first - this appears to be water damaged, so replacing it without stopping the source of water will be pointless, as the replacement will be water-damaged again. Probably the leak is associated with the window (though it could potentially be coming from anywhere higher, all the way to the roof.)

Once the leak is stopped, you cut back to sound drywall and replace the damaged section.

Comment: Also, make sure that's not mold.  If it is, anything that has mold growing on it should be cut out, you do not want that stuff inhabiting your structure.